# Storing encryption key with Android

Tags: android, security, keychain

I have an encryption key that I generate to encrypt some of the fields in my database and the user tokens, etc.

Is there a way in Android to store this key somewhere other than my app? What's happening now is that I cannot create a random encryptor key because if my app is killed and when it is re-opened, a new key is generated and this is not what I want. Because of this problem, I have to create a non-random key so that I can rebuild it after my app is reopened after being killed.

What I want is to be able to create a random key and store this key probably with the OS and I should get this key when my app runs so that I can have a random key which can be the same across one user session. Something like keychain for iCloud.

Hope I am clear with my question.

Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't you be collecting the passphrase from the user? After all, it's the user's data that needs to be protected.

Comment: Its an optional feature. And I do not use that to encrypt the data. Hence, need something like keychain for iOS.

Comment: But that can be trivially defeated, by modifying your app to dump the decrypted data. After all, if your app can get the decrypted data, so can a modified version of your app. The only way to protect the user's data in a way that cannot be so attacked is to use a passphrase from the user.